# Excel column auto calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello i want to calculate on excel without dragging the column.

[image: Example of problem]

I want to make without draging down to calculate if its possible!

Comment: Is "fill-down" acceptable?  _Why is "dragging down" not acceptable?_  What's the actual issue?

Comment: please add more info about what you're actually trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done in Excel with formula alone, but you can return an empty string instead:

```
=IF(OR(A2="",B2="",C2=""),"",A2*C2+B2)
```

Then when there is no information it remains blank.  Then when the info is included the formula resolves.

[image]

---

OR

one can use a table and the formula would automatically be brought down every time a new row is started:

[image]

[image]

---

If one has the new dynamic array formula (Currently only available to Office 365 Insiders) it can be done with a formula like:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/(A2:A100*C2:C100+B2:B100)),""),0)
```

That will automatically spill down with just the one entry of the formula in the first cell.  The caveat to this is that no other entry can be put in the cells below.

[image]

Comment: [Pic1](https://prnt.sc/q1z4e6) do you see the M2 wont calculate i need to drag down and to show me the price [Pic2](https://prnt.sc/q1z5ec)

Comment: As stated it is not possible with formula.  You can drag it down and hide the `0` with `IF()` but you will need a formula in each cell.

Comment: Too bad ok thank you my friend i see your good on excel wish you the best

Comment: @DeathNote if one has Office 365 insiders, then it is possible.  Eventually they will be released to the public at large.  See edit.

Comment: It should be done soo easy but idk why they complicated like this lol

Comment: I dont know what i did i just update and now its calculating good without draging down to show `0` its perfect !!!